# How do i keep two different commands at menu item and sub menu item generated through HierarchicalDataTemplate wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, menu, command

In the below piece of code, nested menu's get generated from an observable collection called CollectionOfAuthors. I've placed two commands, One at the 'ToplevelMenuItem' and another for submenu item (through textblock.InputBindings).
Though the command for submenuitem is working, I am unable to hit the command for the TopLevelMenuItem:

Need to understand what extra i need to do ?

```
<MenuItem x:Name="TopLevelMenuItem" Header="Authors" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfAuthors}"  Command="{Binding DataContext.RefreshAuthorsList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Menu}}"     >
    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Books}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding AuthorName}"/>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding BookName}" >
                                    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                                                        <MouseBinding Command="{Binding DataContext.NavigateToBook, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Menu}}"  MouseAction="LeftClick" />                                                                                                                  
                                   </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
<MenuItem x:Name="TopLevelMenuItem" Header="Authors" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfAuthors}" >
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SubmenuOpened">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.RefreshAuthorsList}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

If you want to prevent from firing command from submenues you will need to pass `{Binding .}` to command, and if param is not type of your ViewModel, then don't fire your action.

Also, you need to add reference to System.Windows.Interactivity and 
`xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"` in your xaml header

Comment: Thank you so much. It's hitting the command now, But It takes me two left clicks to open the menu.

Comment: @user42067 I edited my solution to work on SubmenuOpened instead of MouseLeftClick

Comment: I tried this, Now the command is again not getting fired (neither in single left click nor in double left click)

Comment: @user42067 are you getting any binding errors? Maybe try with RelativeSource `Command="{Binding DataContext.RefreshAuthorsList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Menu}}"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176701/discussion-between-strenat-and-user42067).

Comment: Sure, give me 5 mins.